# how to prevent submitting form twice?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, model-view-controller

I am using MVC to devalop a website.

In a page I am using a modal to open "Create New Item". So I referenced "**jquery.js**".

Also I used "@Ajax.ActionLink()" to load a partial view in modal. So I need to reference to "**jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js**"

Also to validate form, I referenced "**jquery.validate***"

And what's more, I have some files that must be uploaded from "modal form". finally referenced "**jquery.form.min.js**".

I need all this j-query plugins. but the problem is that "form is submitted twice" and i cant remove any of this plugins. What should I do?
this is my form ajax code:

```
 $('#frmEditNewCompany').ajaxForm({
    beforeSubmit: function (arr, $form, options) {
        $(".blockerModal").show();
    },
    onsubmit: function (event) {
        $(".blockerModal").show();
    },
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        alert("after submit")
        if (data.Success == true) {
            $("#dv-modal-lg").modal("hide");
         }
        eval(data.Script);
        $(".blockerModal").hide();
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        $(".blockerModal").hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: you can set a flag to true when the form is submitted once and then in second time you can check if thats true you can prevent the event or stop propagation of the event

Answer (score 0):

In your js just call function at top of your all functions and disable button

```
   $(':input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', true);
```

and enable at last

```
 $(':input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', false);
```

or You can use globle var as boolean and check

```
if(!flag) 
{
flag=true;
//..do
}
else
{
return false;
}
```